# Can you create something like "pre-labels" in a Symfony Form?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Is there a way to make something like Pre-Label in a Symfony Form? I want to format it differently than the normal label. I already tried it with HTML-injection in the normal label-option, like this:

```
$form->add('answer', TextAreaType::class, [
     'label' => '<span>'.$data->category.'</span>'.$data->description
 ]);
```

But this doesn't work. Does someone else has an idea?

Comment: You should try to customize this inside of Twig maybe ? Take a look at this  https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something like a workaround:

```
{% for question in question %}
    <h1>{{ question.vars["value"].question.category.name }}</h1>
    {{ question.vars["value"].question.description }}
    {{ form_errors(question) }}
    {{ form_widget(question, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-control' }}) }}
{% endfor %}
```